# replace quotes in python list

Tags: python, list

```
   e = '[{lat:-34.92967677667683,lng:-62.34831333160395},{lat:-34.93002861969753,lng:-62.360866069793644},{lat:-34.93526211379422,lng:-62.36063016609785},{lat:-34.93571078689853,lng:-62.35996507775451},{lat:-34.935798629937075,lng:-62.34816312789911},{lat:-34.9333358703344,lng:-62.34824895858759},{lat:-34.9320340961022,lng:-62.348334789276066}]'
```

I want to replace `lat` with `"lat"` and `lng` with `"lng"`.
However, this does not work:

```
e.replace('lat', "lat")
```

Comment: "replace quotes in python list" but you posted a string? are you trying to convert this to json?

Comment: @deadshot, yes I am

Comment: @user308827 You have a couple of alternatives offered to you in the answers below (both will work), but do you understand why what you tried above does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `e.replace('lat', '"lat"')`.

Answer (score 1):

`e.replace("lat","\"lat\"")`

You can use `\` for escaping special chars like `"` `'`

Comment: What is the trailing semicolon for?

Comment: @alani sorry for my mistake, I was coding C when I posted my answer. So my mind confused at the moment and putted a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

`e=e.replace("lat","\"lat\"")`

**For replacing with an escape sequence. ,you always have to put an `\` backslash before it**